# Why is this ProgressDailog is not displaying?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog

Here is my code & probelm.

```
static Throwable t= null;
static String responseFromServer = "";
static Activity a ; 
static Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public static String sendToServer(final Activity act, final String data)
{    
      progDailog =  ProgressDialog.show(act, "", " Please wait...", true);
      progDailog.setCancelable(true); //BUT this not displaying 

        Thread th =  new Thread()
         {
         public void run(){
              try{
                  // .........code ... SENDING data to server

                responseFromServer  = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();  
                mHandler.post(showResponse);
                }
              catch (Exception e)
                {
                  t = e;
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                   progDailog.dismiss();
                  mHandler.post(exception);
                 }  
                }
              };
             th.start();
             th.join();

     return responseFromServer;  
    }

     private static  Runnable showResponse = new Runnable()
   {  
    public void run(){
        Toast.makeText( a, responseFromServer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }
    }; 

   private static  Runnable exception = new Runnable()
  {  
    public void run(){
        Toast.makeText( a, t + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }
    };
```

Why progressdialog is not getting displayed ? 
And Where is the correct place to display it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

progressDialog.show() can be executed only from the UI thread.
just do the following:
instead of:

```
  progDailog =  ProgressDialog.show(act, "", " Please wait...", true);
```

use this code:

```
  a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                progDailog =  ProgressDialog.show(act, "", " Please wait...", true);

            }
        });
```

same thing with the dismiss() method

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of AsyncTask other than using Threads. The UI can be handled only from the UI thread. You can not handle the UI thread from the other threads.

For more information on this please read my blog at below link

http://pavandroid.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-create-calendar-in-android.html